# Prove that two polynomials $f,g \in k[X]$ have a common root in $\bar k$ iff $f,g$ have a common factor in $k[X])$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-curves

I am here giving the source of the problem how I was stuck, if someone want to skip this history then please concentrate on the heading:

I was reading the book of [Milne on elliptic curves](http://www.jmilne.org/math/Books/ectext5.pdf). At page $16$ in the proof of Proposition $1.24$ **part b** he has written that

> We know that $r=0$ iff $f$ and $g$ have a common factor in $k(X)[Y]$

Now I tried to elaborate this part a bit, first of all, all the readers might have a look at the definition of resultant at page no $14$ of the same book and the Proposition $1.22$ at page no $15$.

Proposition $1.22$ at page no $15$ states

> The resultant $\operatorname{Res}(f,g)=0$ iff
>
> a) both $s_0$ and $t_0$ are zero; or
>
> b)the two polynomials have a common root in $\bar k$(equivalently, a common factor in $k[X])$.

Now if you see the proof of Proposition $1.22$, you will find out that the part

> the two polynomials have a common root in $\bar k$

is proved but why it is equivalent to

> a common factor in $k[X]$

this part is missing. If someone could give me a proof of this, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both are equivalent to the assertion that the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $f$ and $g$ is $0$.

---

Another approach is this one: if they have a common root $\alpha\in\overline k$, then their greatest common divider cannot be $1$, since it must be a multiple of $x-\alpha$. But the greatest common divider is polynomial with coefficients in $k$. So,  $\gcd\bigl(f(x),g(x)\bigr)$ is a common factor and it is not a constant polynomial. On the other and, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common factor $h(x)\in k[x]$ which is non-constant, then $h(x)$ has a root $\alpha\in\overline k$, which will be a root of both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: I didn't get this part "if they have a common root $\alpha\in\overline k$, then their greatest common divider cannot be $1$, since it must be a multiple of $x-\alpha$". If the two polynomials $f,g$ would be irreducible in $k[x]$ then what would happen?

Comment: @Shadow Whe two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are irreducible in $k[x]$ and have a common root in $\overline k$, then there is a $c\in K\setminus\{0\}$ such that $g(x)=c\times f(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I think I can get the argument using minimal polynomial. If they have root $a$ then $min(a,k)$ divides $f$ and $g$. Now if either of them would be irreducible then that would be the minimal polynomial. But I am wondering if there would be any other simple justification of the " " line without going into Galois theory or not!!

Comment: @Shadow I know nearly nothing about Galois theory. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common root $\alpha\in\overline k$, then both of them are multiples of $x-\alpha$. Since they have a common divisor with degree $1$, their greatest common divisor cannot be $1$.

Comment: But the thing is that the common divisor is in an extension of $k$. I don't know whether I can convey my doubt properly to you or not. Simply I can say that I have to show that $gcd(f,g)$ in $\bar k$ is same as the $gcd(f,g)$ in $k$.

Comment: @Shadow But they *are* equal. Think how you actually compute $\gcd\bigl(f(x),g(x)\bigr)$. You do it using the Euclidian alrgorithm. So, if you start with coefficients in $k$, then they remain in $k$. If you started all over again thinking that the coefficients actually live in $\overline k$, that would change nothing, right?!

Comment: Yes, I think that I am getting your point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If they have common root $a$, consider the Galois group of $G$ $[k(a):k]$, you have for every $g\in G, f^g(a)=f(g(a))=0$, this implies that the $g(a)$ is a root of $a$ for every $g\in G$, we deduce that the minimal polynomial of $a$ divides $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Yes, or even without any of the Galois fanciness: Factor $f$ and $g$ into irreducible polynomials. $a$ must be a root of one of the irreducibles in each factorization, so the minimal polynomial of $a$ appears on each side.